# awk search in specific columns

Tags: awk

We have a file like this (with many more lines):

> BeginJobID=S0065546 JESMSGLG(1/281)  jname=CICWCMWD  queue=EXECUTION
>   JESMSGLG(2/281) BeginJobID=S0065568 jname=CICWWUWD  queue=EXECUTION
>   JESMSGLG(3/281)  jname=CICWMCWD BeginJobID=S0065569 queue=EXECUTION
>   JESMSGLG(4/281)  jname=CICWTQ11  queue=EXECUTION BeginJobID=S0065599
>   BeginJobID=S0065600 JESMSGLG(5/281) queue=EXECUTION jname=CICWFA11
>   JESMSGLG(6/281)  jname=CICWFA21 BeginJobID=S0065601 queue=EXECUTION
>   JESMSGLG(7/281)  jname=CICWFY11 BeginJobID=S0065602 queue=EXECUTION
>   BeginJobID=S0065603 JESMSGLG(8/281)  jname=CICWFY21  queue=EXECUTION
>   BeginJobID=S0065604 JESMSGLG(9/281)  jname=CICWFQ11  queue=EXECUTION
>   BeginJobID=S0065605 JESMSGLG(10/281)  queue=EXECUTION  jname=CICWFT11
>   JESMSGLG(11/281)  jname=CICWFT21  queue=EXECUTION BeginJobID=S0065606
>   JESMSGLG(12/281)  jname=CICWFT31  queue=EXECUTION BeginJobID=S0065607
>   JESMSGLG(13/281)  jname=CICWFT41  queue=EXECUTION BeginJobID=S0065608
>   BeginJobID=S0065609 JESMSGLG(14/281)  jname=CICWGA11  queue=EXECUTION
>   BeginJobID=S0065612 JESMSGLG(15/281)  jname=CICWGA21  queue=EXECUTION
>   JESMSGLG(16/281) BeginJobID=S0065613 jname=CICWGQ11  queue=EXECUTION
>   BeginJobID=S0065614 JESMSGLG(17/281)  queue=EXECUTION  jname=CICWGY11
>   BeginJobID=S0065615 JESMSGLG(18/281)  jname=CICWGT21  queue=EXECUTION
>   BeginJobID=S0065616 JESMSGLG(19/281)  jname=CICWTT41  queue=EXECUTION
>   JESMSGLG(20/281) BeginJobID=S0065617 jname=CICWGT11  queue=EXECUTION

I would like to know an awk simple command to make 2 reports like these:

1. executing: `awk_simple_command_(jname=)`
   result:

```
CICWCMWD
CICWWUWD
CICWMCWD
CICWTQ11
CICWFA11
CICWFA21
CICWFY11
CICWFY21
CICWFQ11
CICWFT11
CICWFT21
CICWFT31
CICWFT41
CICWGA11
CICWGA21
CICWGQ11
CICWGY11
CICWGT21
CICWTT41
CICWGT11
```

2. executing: `awk_simple_command_(BeginJobID=)`
   result:

```
S0065546
S0065568
S0065569
S0065599
S0065600
S0065601
S0065602
S0065603
S0065604
S0065605
S0065606
S0065607
S0065608
S0065609
S0065612
S0065613
S0065614
S0065615
S0065616
S0065617
```

Comment: Does your data file contain hard line breaks, or are your columns delimited only by a space?

Answer (score 1):

In the case that your input data file contains columns delimited only by spaces, no newlines, here's one way to solve the problem using awk:

**reports.awk**

```
BEGIN {
  /* Split records on the space character */
  RS=" ";
  /* Within each record, split the components (fields) on the '=' character */
  FS="=";
}
/* When the first field is the one requested (colname), 
   print the second field. */
$1 == colname { print $2; }
```

Then, assuming your data file is named "*data*", you can invoke the program like so:

**$ awk** -f reports.awk colname=*jname data*

Of course, using either colname=*jname* or colname=*BeginJobID* depending on what data you want to extract. This should produce the output you want.

If your data file sometimes uses a newline in lieu of a space, you'll want to convert those to spaces first and pipe the result into awk:

**$ cat** *data* | **tr** "\n" " " | **awk** -f reports.awk colname=*BeginJobID* -

And you can certainly stick that command in a shell script if you'll be using it often.

Comment: very nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to consider using `grep`:

```
grep -o 'jname=[^ ]\+' infile | grep -o '[^=]\+$'
```

And:

```
grep -o 'BeginJobId=[^ ]\+' infile | grep -o '[^=]\+$'
```